# How to make exe/tar.bz2 from .o file in G++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, exe, tar

Is there any way to make exe or tar.bz2 fiel from .o file in G++? Must I use nasm or any else program for making axe and tar.bz2, or it is possible in G++?

Comment: g++ -o x x.o && tar cjvf x.tar.bz2 x

Comment: What?  Are you talking about a self-extracting (compressed) .exe file?  If so, that has nothing to do with g++, and the bzipping doesn't either.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- To make an exe, use the linker: `g++ -o myprog myob1.o myob2.o`
- To make a compressed archive, use tar: `tar cjf myarchive.tar.bz2 /path/to/all/my/files/`
- To make an [axe](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Axe), use two sticks and three diamonds.